# Selecting Visible Cells using SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

Tags: excel, vba

The idea of my code to **Union** cells with `Interior.Color = vbYellow` in addition to the cells selected manually.

Then intersect both ranges into one range from ("C:F").

**The problem:** there is a case that invisible cells are added to the final range.

I used `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`.

**How to produce the issue**

With the attached picture:

1. Select range("F3:F4") `V-2620` then fill color with yellow.
2. On column C, filter on value `2620` then fill color with yellow for the visible cells from C3 till C8

The result is one range ("C3:F8"). **Expected** two ranges C3:F4 & C7:F8

[image: example spreadsheet]

```vb
Sub Automatic_Save_Selection()
 
   ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
 
   Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
   Dim crg As Range
   Set crg = ws.UsedRange
   Set crg = crg.Offset(1, 0).Resize(crg.Rows.Count - 1, crg.Columns.Count)   'UsedRange except first Row
 
'____Find by Yellow Color_______________________
 
   With Application.FindFormat
     .Clear
     .Interior.Color = vbYellow
     .Locked = True
   End With
 
    Dim uRng As Range, cel As Variant, FirstAddress As Variant
    Set cel = crg.Find(What:=vbNullString, SearchFormat:=True)
 
    If Not cel Is Nothing Then
      FirstAddress = cel.Address
        Do
            If uRng Is Nothing Then
                Set uRng = cel
            Else
                Set uRng = Union(uRng, cel)
            End If
                Set cel = crg.Find(What:=vbNullString, after:=cel, SearchFormat:=True)
        Loop While cel.Address <> FirstAddress
    End If
 
'_____Union (Find by Yellow Color) with Manual Selection__________________
 
  Dim rng As Range
 
  If Not uRng Is Nothing Then
     Set rng = Union(Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible), uRng)
   Else
     Set rng = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
  End If
 
  Dim TrimmedRange As Range
   Set TrimmedRange = Intersect(rng, ws.UsedRange.Offset(1))
    Intersect(TrimmedRange.EntireRow, ws.Range("C:F")).Select
 
End Sub
```

Comment: What is `Selection` in `Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`? "C3:C8" range?

Comment: @FaneDuru It is used to process the selection incase there aren't any cells filled with yellow color

Comment: But, is it "C3:C8" range. Correct?

Comment: @FaneDuru yes correct and that's the issue , that final range contains invisible cells

Answer (score 1):

All previous suppositions were not correct!

Only now I observed that your code starts with:

```
  ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
```

which generates the problem, `Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` being all the range and that's why the returned `Union` `Intersected` range...

The good part from this story, is that I built a function able to extract in an array the filtering criteria, range and items of a existing filter and refilter the range based on the previously extracted array...

So, comment or delete the code line in discussion and use the initial scenario without any problem! :)

Comment: @Leedo Please, download from [here](https://easyupload.io/1r86db) the updated working workbook.

Comment: Appreciate your efforts and point me to the main issue

Comment: I am driving. Try ApplyFilter, or something like that. I uil investigate when I will be at home

Comment: I found out something may help. If I select any cells or filled cells with yellow color **with condition** no other cells on the same row(s) are selected or filled with yellow color, **then** the issue disappeared.

Comment: @Leedo I am afraid I cannot understand what you mean... Do you still use `Find` with `searchingFormat` and it does not 'demolish' the filter, doing what you try explaining? I think I can create a `function` to extract the filtered range, the column(s) having a filter and its criteria in an array and a `sub` able to recreate the filtering based on the previously extracted data.

Comment: With my own code , I will not select or color cells that corresponding row have already colored cells.
In this case my code works correctly. Kindly watch this video  https://easyupload.io/wyz279

Comment: I made it. the trick is to put `Selection.EntireRow.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` into a **Static Variable** e.g `Selc` at the beginning of code (Just below Sub..).
Then I replaced all selection on the code with `Selc`. Sure I thank you for pointing me that (“using Find with searchingFormat parameter, the filter is automatically switched to ShowAllData”)

Comment: I just noticed that you updated your answer.
But, `ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.ShowAllData` is very important in my code logic, without using it, the result is only visible filtered cells will be included on the final range. Anyhow,I will post my answer.